# how to direct php version to php in LAMPP to set default?

Tags: server, bash, apache2, php, lamp

i'm just newbie in ubuntu

i have install php before install lamp, when i type "which php" ==> /usr/bin/php
not to direct in directory php in LAMP

because php in LAMPP have enable mcrypt...but php in default now doesn't active mcrypt..how  to set php in LAMPP to default ? i have tried to input "alias php='/opt/lampp/php'" in .bash_profile and .bashrc, but it's still not work,, but when i type "php -v " ==> bash: /opt/lampp/php: Is a directory

how can i fix it ?

Thx

Comment: The error is due to broken alias, remove it and post `whereis php` command output and `echo $PATH` output, please.

Comment: @Letizia whereis php ==> php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/X11/php /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

echo $PATH ==> /home/ihsan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/home/ihsan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin:/home/ihsan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ihsan/.rvm/bin

please help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have two **php** executable: one located in **/usr/bin** and another in **/opt/lampp/bin**.

When you type `php` in your terminal, `bash` search it in `$PATH` directory list, and it found `php` in **/usr/bin**, so **/usr/bin/php** is executed.

If you want to exec `/opt/lampp/bin/php`, open you `.bashrc` and at the end add this line:

```
      PATH=/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH
```

Once saved .bashrc, exec:

```
      source .bashrc
```

or close/open your terminal and try re-do your **php** command.

Comment: hei...it's work!thx :D